# npm uninstall not working for ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I have ionic cli installed in my PC
Windows 10 OS

as per new ionic release the beta has to be uninstalled and new ionic need to be installed.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases

But when I try to uninstall ionic using npm

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

also

```
npm uninstall -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
```

after uninstall
I did

```
npm list -g
```

the ionic was not shown in the output.

But upon everything when I type

```
ionic -v or ionic --version
```

I still see ionic 2.0.0-beta25 in my console.

Tried this multiple times and also there was a solution in forum by one who says there might be old entry. But I am not sure from where this is getting picked.

Is there a way to find out where npm is picking this or where it is installed?
I cant find it under my npm directory.

C:\Users\Bala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Output of **Where ionic**

```
C:\>where ionic
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ionic
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ionic.cmd
```

Comment: Could you include in your question the output of the following command? `where ionic`

Comment: @cartant  should I delete that?

Comment: To me, that doesn't look like a typical NPM location. I have no idea how it got there, so I don't know the best/cleanest way to remove it. But, yes, I guess it has to go.

Comment: Yeh it worked. Thanks a lot